# How to rework a document with excessively many typesetting commands defined?

Tags: bold, boldmath

Edit:

I resolved my problem, but not in a way that directly addressed the original question. Still, I think my experience may be helpful to some.

Instead of directly addressing the issue of bolding, I stepped back and investigated the 'real' problem. I had defined so many commands that a change in notation had me wanting to change the way `\bm` works rather than changing my formatting macros.

So the question became: how could I define typesetting and notational macros in a way that would be easy to change in future? (I had accepted that I would just have to suffer through fixing the mess I already made.)

### Orignial Question:

**Is there a method or command for bolding only non-subscript or non-superscript characters?**

I have a document with many named variables defined using the pattern shown in the example. I would like to be able to write something like `$\bmnonscript{\namedvariable{i,j}}$` and have it produce the same result as `${\bm{\namedvariable{}}}_{i,j}$`.

Edit: An initial suggestion I recieved was to simply exclude the subscript from `\namedvariable`, but this is not possible since some variables are deifined with subscripts *always* present. MWE updated. See `\varwithsub`

MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\namedvariable}[1]{v_{#1}}
\newcommand{\varwithsub}[1][]{\ifstrempty{#1}{\nu_{sub}}{\nu_{sub, #1}}}

\begin{document}
Currently works as desired: \\
$\namedvariable{}$ \\
$\namedvariable{i}$ \\
$\bm{\namedvariable{}}$ \\

But I want \textbackslash bm\{\textbackslash namedvariable\{i, j\}\} to produce\\
${\bm{\namedvariable{}}}_{i,j}$\\
not\\
$\bm{\namedvariable{i, j}}$.\\

We want to be able to deal with variables that are defined with a subscript.\\
$\varwithsub$\\
$\varwithsub[1]$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `${\bm{\namedvariable{}}}_{i,j}$` can be more simply (and better) written as `$\bm{\namedvariable}_{i,j}$` all the extra braces prevent proper kerning of the subscript. (if you define `\namedvariable` to take no arguments and just be v)

Comment: That errors because an argument is not given; 'Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of `\namedvariable`. `$\bm{\namedvariable}`'.  In a similar vein `$\bm{\namedvariable{}}_{i,j}$` gives a 'double subscript' warning. Does the empty subscript in `\namedvariable{}` really affect the kerning of the subscript? thought it woud just be rendered as 0 by 0 box and have no effect.

Comment: the empty subscript has an effect as does the extra {} around the outside, in combination they prevent the subscript "cutting in" to letters like f or \Gamma.  but if you just had `\newcommand\namedvaraiable{v}` it's much easier: `\namedvariable`, `\namedvariable_{i,j}`, `\bm\namedvariable`, `\bm\namedvariable_{i,j}`

Comment: Sorry, I missed the second part of your answer (tired). I have updated the question. Taking the subscript out is not an option without some extra work since many of the defined variables always have scripts present. What is a better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Brief

After some digging and a lot of struggling with trying to include environment and scope checks in my conditional definitions in an attempt to somehow pass the main character to `\bm` and then glue the subscript to the processed, bolded character afterwards I had to come to terms with the fact that it would be easier to redo the entire document.

I don't know if this is correct procedure on StackExchange but I will answer my own question not with an answer to the original question, but with how I addressed the core problem using simplified examples. I will then edit the question to reflect this, in the hopes that someone else with my inexperience may find this in future and avoid the headache I gave myself.

**The Main Lessons**

When trying to 'separate content from formatting', consider if your means of separation fulfils the actual goal of this modus operandi. The goal, that is, of *saving time in the case of a need to change formatting*.

Less typing $\neq$ more easily changed formatting.

### Full Story

What happened here, and was the impetus behind my question, was that I began with several variable definitions and notational conventions:

```
\newcommand{\xraw}{\tilde{x}}
\newcommand{\xnormed}{x}
\newcommand{\xapprox}{\hat{x}}
```

If this had been the end of it, I would still look back on this as an acceptable decision. This way I could write things like `$\xnormed$ is the result of applying some norm to $\xraw$` and if something meant my notation had to change the body of my document would not be affected, just the file which included all the above definitions.

This, however, is where the problem (unknown to me) appeared. Satisfied that I had divorced content from formatting I continued to add definitions as needed.

```
\newcommand{\yraw}{\tilde{y}}
\newcommand{\ynormed}{y}
\newcommand{\yapprox}{\hat{y}}
```

Because I only added these definitions one at a time I did not process how much time was being spent copy-pasting the original definitions and then editing a character or two in each. Soon I had hundred of lines of definitions including ones that looked like

```
\DeclareBoldMathCommand{\bx}{x}
\newcommand{\bxraw}{\tilde{\bx}}
```

for *every* variable. I had 3-10 commands for each letter of the Latin alphabet, some Greek, with upper and lowercase variants for most. I then started including conditional definitions:

```
\newcommand{\pitchsb}[1][]{
 \ifstrempty{#1}
 {\theta_{sb}}
 {\theta_{sb, #1}}
}
```

The above still seemed fine to me, until I wanted a bold variant:

```
\newcommand{\bpitchsb}[1][]{
 \ifstrempty{#1}
 {\btheta_{sb}}
 {\btheta_{sb, #1}}
}
```

would have been the way to go according to my previous pattern, but this need coincided with me having to change a notational standard and then being hit with the realisation that I had to change *hundreds* of error-prone definitions (it's easy to make a mistake when you're editing essentially the same thing 100 times). This realisation meant that I did not want to duplicate definitions further, since I had now intuited that in doing so I had made my document's formatting exceedingly painful to adjust. So I asked (badly), not how to fix my document, but how to modify the behaviour of `\bm` in order to cooperate with what I already had.

Really, it was easier (for me) to spend several hours writing regex expressions to search-and-replace my mess with a better system than to figure out how to keep working with my mistakes.

I wanted boldface to represent vectors, so I redefined `\vec` for this purpose, and replaced everything in my document. `\xraw` has become `\raw{x}` and `\bxnormedapprox` has become `\approx{\normed{\vec{x}}}`. This involved more typing, but still divorces content from formatting.

### Moral of the Story

1. `\newcommad{\raw}[1]{\tilde{#1}}` is easier to change than 100 lines
   of `\necommand{\araw}{\tilde{a}}`, `\necommand{\braw}{\tilde{b}}`,
   ... even though both variants have the same amount of division
   between content and formatting in-text: `Consider the unnormalised apple variable \raw{a}` vs. `Consider the unnormalised apple variable \araw`.
2. `\raw{\vec{x}}_{\text{bloop}}` may be more typing than `\bxrawbloop`, but it is much,
   much, much more maintainable.

---

*I thought that answering here and sharing my experience would be better than deleting the question since I doubt this is the first or last time someone wastes time like this, and my experience may be worthwhile for people who would otherwise do the same thing I did.*